# Blackberry - Secure API error on simulator

Tags: java, blackberry

Today while programming, I suddenly started to get a JVM Error 104 and the except read "Error starting XXXX: Module 'XXXX' attempts to access a secure API". I hadn't gotten them before and I wasn't doing anything too radical. I undid my work to a point where it was previously working and the error continued to show. I am aware that certain functions require code to be signed, but the documentation says that even functions that need to be signed will work in the simulator. (using JRE 4.6, version 1,1 of the plugin, on a Bold 9000 simulator)

Any ideas on how to remove this error so I can continue working?

EDIT: I noticed that it works fine on the "Blackberry-SDK - 8900" but I get the error when using the "SimPackage - 4.6.0.307_9000 - 9000"

EDIT: It only seems to be a problem with the "SimPackage - 4.6.0.307_9000 - 9000" simulator which I downloaded seperately from the Blackberry Developers page.

EDIT: Clearing simulator data seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which development environment you're using. If it is JDE, goto Edit -> Preferences, select the Simulator Tab and ensure "Enable Device Security" is un-checked. If you're using Eclipse you will have to find the appropriate mechanism or perhaps someone eles knows.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. The enable security is in Run -> Run Configurations -> Simulator Tab -> "Security Check Enabled" checkbox.

I have verified that it is unchecked.

Comment: cleaning the simulator turned out to do the trick. But thanks.